# Program crashes because of wrong usage of slots and signals

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

What I'm trying to do is to call an time consuming operation (`MockClamWrapper::loadDatabase()`) in a separate thread at the moment of creation of my window and then to update my window once the operation is completed. Here is the code that I have.

**MockClamWrapper.h**

```
class MockClamWrapper : QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT    
public:
    MockClamWrapper();
    ~MockClamWrapper();
    bool loadDatabase(unsigned int *signatureCount=NULL);
Q_SIGNALS:
    void databaseLoaded();
};
```

**MockClamWrapper.cpp**

```
bool MockClamWrapper::loadDatabase(unsigned int *signatureCount){
    QThread::currentThread()->sleep(10);
    databaseLoaded();
    return true;
}
```

**MainWindow.h**

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include "mockclamwrapper.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void enableWindow();
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    MockClamWrapper *clam;
    void initWindow();
};
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect((QObject*)clam, SIGNAL(databaseLoaded()),(QObject*)this,SLOT(enableWindow()));
    QFuture<void> fut = QtConcurrent::run(this,&MainWindow::initWindow);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::initWindow(){
    clam->loadDatabase(NULL);
}

void MainWindow::enableWindow(){
    ui->checkFileButton->setEnabled(true);
}
```

The program compiles, but it crashes right after start. I assume that I do something wrong with slots and signals, but can't find my mistake.

Comment: Why are you casting to QObject in the connect() call? You don't need to.

Comment: @HamishMoffatt I get the "C2243: 'type cast' : conversion from 'MockClamWrapper *' to 'const QObject *' exists, but is inaccessible" error if I don't.

Comment: `class MockClamWrapper : !!!public!!! QObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for crash is that you are not making any instance of the class `MockClamWrapper`. In the connect statement, you are referencing a pointer that points to nothing. Make a new object and then connect :

```
clam = new MockClamWrapper();
connect(clam, SIGNAL(databaseLoaded()), this, SLOT(enableWindow()));
```

Comment: That was dumb.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: To prevent such errors in future - use smart pointers. Because it's much easier to catch and debug null reference exception.